# "Joint" or "Join": What is the name for the place where two pieces of wood are fastened together?

Tags: joinery

When speaking in my woodshop, I can't quite tell whether people are saying *joint* or *join* when referring to the place where two pieces of wood are glued (or nailed) together. I know the practice is known as *joinery* but in my use of the English language, *joint* seems more appropriate. Of course, it doesn't help that a *jointer* is a tool for a completely different thing.

Comment: Also the person is doing the work is called a joiner. Just to add to the fun, there is the old spelling as well: joyner who makes joynts.

Comment: You shouldn't have a joint until you're done joining the pieces.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *Joiner*<sup>*</sup> uses a *jointer* to *joint* ** smooth surfaces on pieces of wood, which he then *joins* together to make a *joint*. The practice of doing so is called *joinery*.

Gotta love English!

<sup>hat tips to *ewm and **datUser for the additional confusion!</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Good question - given that wood working and the language we use to describe it are hundreds of years old, I will assume both words have been used interchangeably here and there.

In my experience, I have heard it as a joint (being the noun describing two or more pieces of wood stuck together). I felt that I should consult a higher authority, so I went to Joseph Moxon's [Mechanick Exercises or Doctrine of handy-works (1703)](http://books.google.com/books?id=t_IRCzjTf08C&dq), one of the earliest books on woodworking in English. Thanks to google, I could search the text.

Moxon is consistent: *join* is a verb ("these two Pieces are with Glew commonly join'ed together", p.64) and *joint* is a noun ("...smear the Glew well upon the Joint of each piece you are to Glew together", p.105). I hope that helps.

Comment: You provided the answer that makes perfect sense in the noun and verb descriptions.

Comment: Good answer, the part of speech I think is it exactly.  I made an edit suggestion to make it a bit more readable with paragraphs.  We also don't typically use salutations in StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about the word for the place where too pieces of wood meet. This is definitely a **joint** and probably should not be called a **join**.

However to further add to the fun here, when referencing the machine known as a [Jointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jointer), I have always heard the action of using this particular tool described by the verb **joint**.

For Example:

> "Be sure you check the fence on the jointer table before you **joint** those boards. I was **jointing** something at a 2 degree angle earlier today, so it may not be square."

Not sure if this is colloquial or correct english, but I have heard this verb used constantly in several shops I have worked in over the years when referring to the act of using the jointer. I have not ever heard the more general act of creating a joint called **jointing** to be clear, just the act of using the machine. This would merely be referred to as **joining** or cutting joinery.

It is worth nothing many people call the machine **jointer** a *joiner* which is incorrect and very hard to distinguish from the correct name. :)